# Tkinter grid propagate and scrollbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid

I have a text widget I want to set at a specific size in pixels. To do this I have put it and a scrollbar in a frame with `grid_propate` set to `False` as follows:

```
with open (file_name) as f: c = f.read ()
self.holder = Frame (self.main_frame)
self.holder.grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
self.holder.grid_propagate (False)
self.holder.grid_columnconfigure (0, weight = 1)
self.holder.grid_rowconfigure (0, weight = 1)
self.text = Text (self.holder)
self.text.grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
self.text.insert ("end", c)
self.scroll = Scrollbar (self.holder, orient = "vertical", command = self.text.yview)
self.scroll.grid (row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")
self.text.config (yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
```

However, in setting `grid_propagate` to `False`, the scrollbar behaves strangely (when at the top, it shows no scrollability - if such a word exists - then once further down it shows that you can scroll further than you can. It is hard to describe so please try the code before picking me up on this). With it set to `True`, everything works perfectly. How can this be fixed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is incomplete. It lacks the imports, the class that holds the code, and you never give the frame any size. When I fix all of those problems with the most obvious solutions, the scrollbar works fine for me.

Comment: Your code is not testable without some guessing as to the structure of your class. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for your comment. By specifying the width and height of the main frame I got it to work: `width = self.main_frame.winfo_width (), height = self.main_frame.winfo_height ()`

Comment: Yes.. You claimed right up front you wanted to give it an explicit width. I assumed you were doing that somewhere. When you turn geometry propagation off, it's up to you to give the widget an explicit width. That's the whole point of turning geometry proipagation off.